# Quick way to create a symlink?

Tags: macos, finder

Dragging a folder in Finder while pressing Command + Option (<kbd>⌘</kbd> +  <kbd>⌥</kbd>) creates an alias. But is there a quick and similar way to create a symlink this way?

Comment: Frustrating, isn’t it?  I would prefer a symlink to an alias about 80% of the time. I like the solution from @user3439894, and in combination with a launcher (lots of good, open source ones available), or simply _Automator_, you can streamline the process very aptly.

Comment: [XtraFinder](https://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder) adds this feature, among other things. It's $5, but has an unlimited (in time and in features) trial. Strongly recommend.

Comment: With XtraFinder, Make Symbolic Link is a menu command not a drag and drop. Also XtraFinder requires System Integrity Protection be disabled to install and does not work with macOS 10.12 with SIP enabled nor is it guaranteed to work with OS X 10.11 and macOS 10.13 with SIP enabled. IMO Frankly not worth the hassle!

Answer (score 7):

**macOS** does not have a native *drag and drop* method to create a *symlink* in the same manner as creating an *alias* in **Finder**. By default, *symlinks* are created by using `ln` from the command line in **Terminal**.

---

In **Terminal**:

```
$ ln
usage: ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]
       ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... target_dir
       link source_file target_file
$
```

For additional details, use: `man ln`

---

For a homegrown solution using **Automator** and **AppleScript**, the following is a bare-bones example of an **Automator** Service (*QuickAction* in **macOS Mojave**) that when assigned a keyboard shortcut, e.g. **⌘S** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, will create a *symlink* of the *selected items* in **Finder** at the *selected destination folder* that is brought up by pressing e.g. **⌘S**:

This *Service* (QuickAction) will be available on the **Services** menu in **Finder** or from right-click **Context** menu, and or the assigned keyboard shortcut once an *item* or *items* are selected in **Finder**.

Bare-bones *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    if input is equal to {} then return

    activate

    set posixPath to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt ¬
        "Select destination folder for Symlink..." default location ¬
        (path to desktop folder) with invisibles)

    repeat with thisItem in input
        set thisItem to POSIX path of (thisItem as alias)
        try
            do shell script "ln -s " & quoted form of thisItem & ¬
                space & quoted form of posixPath
        end try
    end repeat

end run
```

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes you have write privileges at the *selected destination folder*, other then the *selected items source folder*, and as coded only creates the *symlink* if it doesn't already exist. Changes can be made to the *code* to accommodate other options.

[image: Make Symbolic Link Automator Service]

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and, other then a single `try` *statement*, does not contain any additional error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: Excellent. Do you think there's perhaps a way to overwrite Finder's native _drag and drop_ behaviour?

Comment: @thomasdecrick, Sorry, no, I do not know of a way to override the default behavior. That said, since one has to press **⌘⌥** and use the mouse anyway, setting up a keyboard shortcut e.g. **⌘S** for the Automator Service and some mouse clicks is not a bad alternative. Also, keep in mind that if you already have the destination folder open in another Finder window, you can always drag an drop the folder into the choose folder window to quickly change it to that location and not necessarily have to manually navigate to it.

Comment: If you like keyboard shortcuts, check this one out: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/469197.  It uses Hammerspoon which is quite a nice add-on for macOS

Answer (score 6):

The service [SymbolicLinker](https://github.com/nickzman/symboliclinker/releases) will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/), the following will create symbolic links of the items you have selected in Finder when you press control, option, command, W.

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"⌃", "⌥", "⌘"}, "W",  function()
    local frontMost = hs.application.frontmostApplication()
    if frontMost:name() == "Finder" then
        local success, result, descriptor = hs.osascript.applescriptFromFile("scpt/finderGetSelectedFiles.scpt")
        if success then
            for index, value in ipairs(result) do
                local cmd = "ln -s '" .. value .."' '" .. value .. " link'"
                print(cmd)
                print(hs.execute(cmd))
            end
        else
            -- maybe print some sort of error???
        end
    end
end)
```

where `scpt/finderGetSelectedFiles.scpt` (located in your `~/.hammerspoon` folder) contains the following:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selectedItems to selection
    set posixPaths to {}
    repeat with selectedItem in selectedItems
        set theItem to selectedItem as alias
        set posixPath to POSIX path of theItem
        set end of posixPaths to posixPath
    end repeat
    return posixPaths
end tell
```